# How to get the timer of running application?

Tags: java, android, android-timer

I need to get the timer in Application manager. I have 2 application and I need to get the time, both in the list of running applications in Settings.

[image]

Here the question arises only on the time. But I still need to get a timer application. First I have to get an id or application package, and then only the timer

As you can see, there is a timer indicates when service is running. But I need to get a timer of application when runned, not services time. How do I get it? I do not even have a presentation where you want to dig, how to get them?

Comment: you can use sharedpreference to save time whenever app starts. calculate time difference between installed time and current time

Comment: If I need timers all applications. How, then, be?